# Using App ID & Secret as access token to list a Facebook page's tabs returns empty list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs

I'm looking for a way to be able to manage our page's Facebook tabs automatically, without needing an admin to log in. I tried using using the related app's ID and secret as [suggested in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25259974/134014) ([FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)) and that gets me access to the page and it seems all of the data on the page except tabs. When I try to access [`/{page-id}/tabs`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/tabs) I get `{ data: [] }` as the response. Page API endpoints I have tried work fine.

I have also tried `/{pageId}?fields=access_token` as [suggested in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17234650/134014) and it just retuned the app ID, the access token field completely absent. I tried that again using a user access token and it returned a token, but the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) said the token expires in one hour.

I'm trying to automate the removal and reordering of tabs, but if the user needs to log in an hour before this happens it defeats the purpose. Is there any way I can get a permanent access token for a page that will return tabs? Is there any way to accomplish this with the app id/secret access token method?

Comment: (Why didn’t you) read the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_changes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/tabs/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extendingpagetokens

Comment: Thank you, @CBroe. Those links are very helpful. I missed them when I was looking through the docs. This is the first time I've really delved into the Facebook API and I am still unfamiliar with the docs. I looked on those pages but missed those sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to get an access token for a page with only an App ID and secret. You have to have a user with access log in and give you their access token. However, with [CBroe's helpful links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156016/using-app-id-secret-as-access-token-to-list-a-facebook-pages-tabs-returns-emp#comment44689578_28156016) I was able to [get a never expiring page access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/134014). You can see the [steps I took in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/134014) to almost the same question.